# Need help aligning my header/footer with my main body

Tags: html, css

So I'm working on an assignment that builds on itself at the end of every chapter in my textbook, and my professor took points off for the header image and the footer not being aligned correctly with the main content of my page, but I can't seem to figure out how to fix this problem.

```css
body {
    background-color: #3F2860;
    color: #3F2860;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    header {
    background-image: url(lilyheader.jpg);
    height: 150px;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    position: relative;
    }

    h1 {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-left: 2em;
    }

    nav {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 1em;
    float: left;
    width: 160px;
    }


    nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-style: outset;
    border-color: #CCCCCC;
    padding: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    }

    nav a:link {color: #3f2860;}
    nav a:visited {color: #497777;}
    nav a:hover {color: #a26100; border: 3px inset #333333;}

    nav ul { 
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0; 
    }

    .studio {
    font-style: italic;
    }

    footer {
    background-color: #9BC1C2;
    font-size: .60em;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1em;
    }

    #wrapper {
    width: 80%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    min-width: 1200px;
    max-width: 1480px;
    }

    main {
    padding-left: 2em;
    padding-right: 2em;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 170px;
    padding-top: 1em;
    }


    * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .floatleft {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 4em;
    }

    .clear {
    clear: both;
    }

    header,nav,main,footer {display: block;}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Path of Light Yoga Studio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yoga.css">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">
    </script>
    <! [endif]-->
    </head>

    <header>
    <h1>Path of Light Yoga Studio</h1>
    </header>
    <main>
    <div id='wrapper'>

    <nav>
    <ul>
    <li><a href = "index.html">Home</a></li> 
    <li><a href = "classes.html">Classes</a></li> 
    <li><a href = "schedule.html">Schedule</a></li>
    <li><a href = "contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
 
    <img class='floatleft' src='yogadoor2.jpg' alt="Yoga Door">
    
    <h2>Find Your Inner Light</h2>
    <p><span class="studio">Path of Light Yoga Studio</span> provides all levels of yoga practce in a tranquil, peaceful envirionment. Whether you are new to yoga or an experienced practitioner, our dedicated instructors can develop a practice to meet your needs. Let your inner light shine at the <span class="studio">Path of Light Yoga Studio</span>.</p>
 
    <ul>
    <li>Hatha, Vinyasa, and Restorative Yoga Classes</li>
    <li>Drop-ins welcome</li>
    <li>Mats, blocks, and blankets provided</li>
    <li>Relax in our Serenity Lounge before or after your class</li>
    </ul>

    <div class='clear'>
    Path of Light Yoga Studio<br>
    612 Serenity Way<br>
    El Dorado, CA 96162<br><br>
    888-555-5555<br><br><br>
    </div>
    </div>
    <footer>   
    Copyright &copy; 2016 Path of Light Yoga<br>
    </footer>

    </main>
```

I think I formatted that correctly (first time using this site).

Comment: For clarification, the alignment is supposed to make it so the header image and footer come together without any overlap with the main body content.

Comment: ... Why is your header text and background the same color?

Comment: This is an image of what I'm getting https://i.imgur.com/enRPqyG.png

Comment: Right... Image... JSFiddle doesn't have access to image. I'll go add a work-around to JSFiddle

Comment: Updated fiddle to fix problem. Here is new [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c7un9hom/16/). Note, this fiddle is just to display the webpage. It does not solve your alignment issue... Yet.

Answer (score 0):

Alright... So there's a lot of issues with your CSS and you also have invalid HTML. HTML requires a body tag... Which you don't have. Browsers were probably adding this because it's something they do. They take invalid html and guess what the developer was trying to build.

So first of, keep in mind, the base of all html pages is as following:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Next up, there was a lot stuff going on with CSS. The biggest thing I saw involved floats. Floats are a way to easily make a mess. They have their uses; but, usually there is a better way now a days.

Now looking at your alignment problem at its roots...

From what I understand, you want your header and footer to be the same width as the main content and be the same distance from the left of the screen.

You setup your main content to use `#wrapper` div and did aligment with that. This is fine. The problem is how you set stuff up is more directed to a webpage where the header and the footer are glued to top/bottom of the page, and full up the width completely.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
        </header>
        <main>
            <div id="wrapper">
                //This guy had the common margin auto with a width percentage.
            </div>
            <footer>
            </footer>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Having the alignment of the page set on the wrapper means it can't really be applied to the footer and header that well. It will get really messy. Of course this isn't a problem if you the header and footer just take up all the width at the top and bottom of the page.

What did I do to fix this?

First off, let's clean up your HTML. It would make more sense to break your page into 3 pieces. Header, Main, Footer. Right now your footer is inside your main.

So what I did is this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
        </header>
        <main>
            <div id="wrapper">
                //This guy had the common margin auto with a width percentage.
            </div>
        </main>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Next up, I moved the alignment. So instead of having this rule:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 80%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
```

I have these rules:

```
header, main, footer {
  width: 80%; 
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

#wrapper{
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
```

By doing this, we the alignment rules is being applied to the 3 elements inside the body tag. I do NOT apply to this the body tag itself; because, we should avoid changing the width of the body.

Finally, you also had some weird padding on the main element:

```
main {
    padding-left: 2em;
    padding-right: 2em;
}
```

I don't know why this is here; but, I moved that to the body.

```
body {
    padding-left: 2em;
    padding-right: 2em;
}
```

By placing it on the body it will affect the header, main and footer.

Those are the changes to fix alignment. In addition to those changes I removed various rules and statements that might have been causing issues or not... I do not believe these will have any impact on your page; but, just in case if they were required for some unknown reason you should take a look at your requirements and ensure everything is still correct.

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c7un9hom/42/)